# Fail to use the PurchasingService of the Amazon AppStore SDK to implement IAP

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am currently trying to migrate my application from the Google Play Billing to the Amazon IAP system in order to deploy my application on the Amazon AppStore.

I am following the official documentation and use the AppStore SDK in version 3.0.2. I followed all the steps in order to test IAP on the device, meaning:

- added in-app items on the developer console
- exported the list as a json file and push it on the device using ADB
- installed the Amazon App Tester app
- activated the sandbox mode using ADB
- added the AppstoreAuthenticationKey.pem file into the assets

Unfortunately, it does not work. After requesting the PurchasingService , the callbacks of the listener are never called.

According to the logcat, it seems that I have an issue during the signature verification step:

```
SignatureVerifier: Verifying signature of data: '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', signature: 'com.heydenapps.arrowwords', with key: 'OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=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,publicExponent=10001}

AbstractCommandTask: Exception occurred while processing task: com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null
    com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.b.a(AuthenticationTokenVerifier.java:94)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:204)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:131)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

AbstractCommandTask: On Exception!!!!: com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null

MetricsManagerImpl: Recording Metric: Metric: [{reason=null, name=lifeCycle_Events_failure, context=null, subType=AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE, time=1642368595311}]
```

As you can see, an `AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE` is thrown.

I do not know how to fix this issue. I cannot find something about this issue on the Internet nor in the documentation.

Note that my application is not available yet on the store and I currently using the Android Studio debug keystore.

Comment: Check you set up the receivers in your AndroidManifest. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71588959/18483253

Answer (score 0):

1. Use debug build
2. Set sandbox mode

```
adb shell setprop debug.amazon.sandboxmode debug
```