# The PurchasingService of the Amazon AppStore SDK to implement IAP doesnt work

Tags: android, amazon-appstore, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am currently trying to implement the Amazon IAP.

I followed the official documentation and use the AppStore SDK ( version 3.0.3 ).

I followed all the steps in order to test IAP on the device. I dont know if this error is because of not using a amazon fire device because im using a google pixel emulator.

Then I cloned their [demo project](https://github.com/AmazonAppDev/amazon-iap-kotlin?tab=readme-ov-file) but it is also giving the same error in logcat:

Currently im trying to run their demo project (link is given above). Here is the error in Logcat:

```
CommandServiceClient: Binding Service!!!
2024-01-31 21:49:06.233  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           D  CommandServiceClient: Created intent with  action  com.amazon.venezia.CommandService
2024-01-31 21:49:06.240  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           E  CommandServiceClient: CommandServiceException happened, retriesLeft=1
                                                                                                    com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.c: COMMAND_SERVICE_NOT_INSTALLED: null: null
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.e(CommandServiceClient.java:257)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.a(CommandServiceClient.java:181)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:124)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.f(TaskWorkflow.java:78)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.a(TaskWorkflow.java:49)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2024-01-31 21:49:06.242  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           D  CommandServiceClient: Sleeping for 3200 ms
2024-01-31 21:49:09.445  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           D  CommandServiceClient: Binding Service!!!
2024-01-31 21:49:09.445  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           D  CommandServiceClient: Created intent with  action  com.amazon.venezia.CommandService
2024-01-31 21:49:09.447  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           E  CommandServiceClient: CommandServiceException happened, retriesLeft=0
                                                                                                    com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.c: COMMAND_SERVICE_NOT_INSTALLED: null: null
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.e(CommandServiceClient.java:257)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.a(CommandServiceClient.java:181)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:124)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.f(TaskWorkflow.java:78)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.a(TaskWorkflow.java:49)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2024-01-31 21:49:09.449  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           D  AbstractCommandTask: Exception occurred while processing task: com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.c: COMMAND_SERVICE_NOT_INSTALLED: null: null
                                                                                                    com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.c: COMMAND_SERVICE_NOT_INSTALLED: null: null
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.e(CommandServiceClient.java:257)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.d.a(CommandServiceClient.java:181)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:124)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.f(TaskWorkflow.java:78)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.c.b.a(TaskWorkflow.java:49)
                                                                                                        at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2024-01-31 21:49:09.450  9250-9271  Kiwi                    IAPKotlinApp.example.myapp           E  AbstractCommandTask: On Exception!!!!: com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.c: COMMAND_SERVICE_NOT_INSTALLED: null: null
```

I tried other solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734448/fail-to-use-the-purchasingservice-of-the-amazon-appstore-sdk-to-implement-iap/71393893#71393893) but it didnt worked

Comment: Did you install [Amazon Appstore](https://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get/android-download/ref=mas_mbl_ldg) and their IAP [App Tester](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-install-and-configure-app-tester.html) on your emulator?

Comment: Hi! I'm maintaining the samples https://github.com/AmazonAppDev/ . Yes you have to test the Amazon IAP with a Fire OS Device.